# Update CA Certificate Bundle On MAMP

Tags: security, certificate, phpmailer, mamp, ca

I updated MAMP recently to MAMP 6 and my PHPMailer stopped working on my localhost site. It seems that the CA certificate bundle is outdated.

I did a test with MailTrap using the default settings that MailTrap offer for PHPMailer and it worked.

The test settings with MailTrap omit the SMTP `$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;` and a mail is indeed sent.

I've never updated a CA certificate bundle before (let alone on MAMP) and would really appreciate how best to do this.